# displaying data from Firebase with angular

Tags: angularjs, firebase

I am trying to display a table of posts following this tutorial:

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creating-a-web-app-from-scratch-using-angularjs-and-firebase--cms-22391

Part 5 has still not been published, so I took the tutorial all the way to part 4 and am trying to build a post.html view. However, as a beginner in both angular and firebase, I am really struggling.

Here is the code for my post/post.js file:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('myApp.post', ['ngRoute'])

.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
 $routeProvider.when('/post', {
templateUrl: 'post/post.html',
controller: 'PostCtrl'
 });
}])



.controller('PostCtrl', ['$scope','$firebase' ,       function($scope,$firebase) {
$scope.message = 'Hello World';
$scope.viewPost = function(){
    $scope.article.title = "";
    $scope.article.post = "";
    $scope.article= {};
    $scope.myData = new Firebase("https://glowing-fire-6133.firebaseio.com/Posts");
};

$scope.myData.on('value', function(snapshot){
    $scope.article = snapshot.val();

   });
}]);
```

And here is the code for my post.html file

```
<title></title>

<link href="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<link href="assets/css/blog.css" rel="stylesheet">


</head>


<body ng-controller="PostCtrl">
<h1>{{message}}</h1>

    <div ng-repeat="post in posts">
        <h2>{{article.title}}</h2>
        <div>{{article.post}}</div>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

I get no errors or results from this. I made sure to add the

```
'myApp.post', //Post view
```

module to app.js and the  in the index.html but still nothing.

Am I doing or missing something really stupid? I.E. login to the DB etc.?

Thanks for your patience

##Addpost script

```
'use strict';

angular.module('myApp.addPost', ['ngRoute'])

.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
 $routeProvider.when('/addPost', {
templateUrl: 'addPost/addPost.html',
controller: 'AddPostCtrl'
 });
}])

.controller('AddPostCtrl',     ['$scope','$firebase',function($scope,$firebase) {
$scope.AddPost = function(){
var title = $scope.article.title;
    var post = $scope.article.post;

var firebaseObj = new Firebase("https://glowing-fire-6133.firebaseio.com/Posts");
    var fb = $firebase(firebaseObj);

fb.$push({ title: title,post: post}).then(function(ref) {
    console.log(ref); 
}, function(error) {
    console.log("Error:", error);
});

}
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Where is `$scope.posts`? I don't see it in your controller, so there's nothing to loop through.

You should have `$scope.posts = [/* a bunch of post objects*/];`

I actually kinda looks like you should be doing `<div ng-repeat="post in myData">`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I understand your point but how do I make myData into a bunch of $scope.posts objects? Would I have to do something along the lines of myData.items?

Comment: @Cigana it looks like myData is a bunch of post objects to me. Is it not? Admittedly, I don't know Firebase, but that url looks like a request to a controller that returns post objects. Can you show the JSON you get back from that?

Comment: Yes, you are correct it is is a bunch of objects I just don't see how can request it in an object. The way firebase formats the Json-like objects is as follows: `glowing-fire-6133`  (db name)
`Jm9nJDRrIq9Dncfj1gv`   (table I believe)
 `post: post content` 
 `title: post title`

Comment: I have added the addPost script above, I hope it helps.

Comment: @Cigana I need to see what the data looks like that comes back from your request.

Comment: Sorry for some reason I did not see your reply. The data is Firebase (if you are familiar with it) JSON style data just as I highlighted above: Database name, a randomly generated key table ref plus the post which contiains the var title = $scope.article.title; and  var post = $scope.article.post; elements. Is this clearer?